# Appending Quotes to two Concatenated strings in Bash

Tags: string, bash, curl, concatenation

I'm basically doing a test Curl with a simple shell script, and unfortunately when I make my curl command, since I'm passing the parameters programatically, its reading each word in my string as an individual parameter, and trying to resolve them as hosts, which I need to send the entire message as is. Here is the code:

```
Name="Bob"
LISTENER_URL='http://httpbin.org/post'
PAYLOAD="Hello my name is" $NAME
curl --request POST --url $LISTENER_URL --data $PAYLOAD --insecure
```

The output would be curl sends "Hello" to the url, then fails to resolve the hosts:

```
my
name
is
bob
```

I did try the following modifications, but to no avail:

```
 curl --request POST --url $LISTENER_URL --data '"'+$PAYLOAD+'"' --insecure
 curl --request POST --url $LISTENER_URL --data '"'$PAYLOAD'"' --insecure
```

Also tried redeclaring the variable like this:

```
PAYLOAD="\"$PAYLOAD\""
```

Comment: What about quoting the expansions `--data "$PAYLOAD"` etc? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign a value with a space, you need to quote or backslash it:

```
PAYLOAD="Hello my name is $NAME"
```

Similarly, to expand a variable as one word, double quote it:

```
 curl --request POST --url "$LISTENER_URL" --data "$PAYLOAD" --insecure
```